# can a malware for iphone survive to hard reset?

Tags: iphone, spyware

My question is about a malware on the device Iphone 6s.
Can a malware on Iphone survive to an hard factory reset ?
The malware would be installed from the shop where I bought it.It's a second hand device.
IMHO it could be, because the upgrades of ios don't have to be installed after the reset.

Is my assumption correct?